# Things to consider when shooting landscapes in broad daylight

Tags: equipment-recommendation, landscape

While reading through many books as well online resources, I have come across these lines

> best time for landscapes is before sunrise and after sunset, and during a short window around these times

I can understand the reasoning, but sometime you are left with no other choice but to shoot landscapes in day light.
Sometimes we are lucky to get overcast weather but sometimes we are exposed to bright sun light.

I can consider getting some ND filters, but not very sure about what else needs to be taken care of while shooting landscapes in day light

Can any one help me with this?

Comment: After editing, I now see a related question that seems a duplicate - http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/42161/effective-filters-for-daytime-landscape-photography?rq=1

Comment: I don't see that this is a dupe at all. There are things you can do in broad daylight that don't require filters. Hurley refers to sharp shadows, for example.

Answer (score 2):

The quality of your light is always one of the fundamental constraints a photographer must pivot around. With smaller subjects it is possible to bring your own light, but landscape photography generally considers areas too large for artificial lighting, which is why the hour before and after sunrise and sunset are so special -- that is when you are most likely to encounter the best natural light.

But don't let the time of day stop you. You already mentioned the power of clouds and an ND filter, on the equipment front add in ND-Grads, as this will help you deal with huge dynamic range bright sunlight will present with respect to deep shadows (of course you can HDR/Exposure blend for similar results).

Getting past equipment, be open to the harsh midday sun, with its strong shadows find ways to  use it in compositions, e.g. heavy tree canopies make for interesting shadows, sun flare can be (over) used for dramatic effect, etc.

Of course waking up early is still when the magic happens :-)

Comment: Thanks for inputs, i am early riser but sometime you are limited with options and some how i never liked my pics taken in bright sun light.

Answer (score 0):

ND filters won't give you the "quality of light" you get at sunset and sunrise. That's in large part determined not by light intensity (though it plays a part) but colour and the angle of the sun over the horizon (which makes for those nice dramatic shadows).
Also, the air at especially sunrise can often be crisper, cleaner, than later in the day, less pollution and haze.
That said, you can make stunning landscapes at any time of day. It all depends on skill, vision, and situation. Equipment has very little to do with it.